# Is there a better way to display text inline, under images?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display two labels of text inline under two images, but for some reason I cannot figure it out. The images float to the right (as they should), and when I try to float the text in hopes that it aligns underneath the two images, that does not happen.

I also tried a separate container for the label text, and that aligns the text under the images, but then the text is not distributed evenly underneath the two images, as I would expect they would be since they're in their respective containers.

I've tried about everything at this point. I'm not sure what is up as the text is in a span, in its parent div.  Right now, the span #past-label is floating right, close but not quite.

I hope someone has an answer.

```
<article id="issue-wrapper">
    <div id="issue-container">
        <h5><span style="color: #ffffff;">First issue</span>  Fall 2010</h5>
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <h6>Sub Heading</h6>
    </div><!----------issue container end---------->
    <div id="issues">
        <div id="past-cover"><a href="issues/sample-issue.pdf"><img src="image" alt="alt text" /></a>
            <span id="past-label">PDF</span>
        </div>
        <div id="past-cover"><a href="issues/sample-issue.swf"><img src="image" alt="alt text" /></a>
            <span id="past-label">FLASH</span>
        </div>
        <div id="past-cover-mobile"><a href="issues/sample-issue.pdf"><img src="image" alt="alt text" /></a>
            <span id="past-label">PDF</span>
        </div>
    </div><!----------issue covers end---------->
</article><!----------issue wrapper end---------->

<style type="text/css">
    #issue-wrapper {
        background-color:red;
        height:auto;
        padding:30px;
        display:table;
        width:100%;
    }
    #issue-container {
        width:30%;
        height:auto;
        background-color:gray;
        left:0px;
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    #issue-covers {
        background-color:orange;
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        margin:0px;
    }

    #past-cover img {
        float:right;
    }

    #past-cover-mobile img {
        float:right;
        display:none;
    }

    #past-label {
        background-color:blue;
        margin:0px;
        width:auto;
        display:inline;
        float:right;

    }

    h5, h3, h6 {
        width:100%;
        margin:0px;
        font-size:2em;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: If you provide a working jsfiddle which demonstrates your problem, helping you becomes so much easier.

Comment: Don’t float the image itself, but the container that contains the image and the text. (And FYI, ids have to be unique within a document, you are using `past-cover` and `past-label` multiple times.)

Comment: As @CBroe said, you do not need to float everything right, just the wrapping divs / containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float your `#past-cover` elements, not the images. Then set your `<span>` to `display:block`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gea58xd8/1

```
#past-cover {
        float: right;
    }
    #past-cover:after{
        display:table;
        clear:both;
        content:"";
    }
    #past-cover img {
        float:none;
        display:block;
    }

    #past-cover-mobile img {
        float:none;
        display:none;
    }

    #past-label {
        background-color:blue;
        margin:0px;
        width:auto;
        display:block;
        float:none;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like all it took was a few minor adjustments.